npm error TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
I am building docker image from angular code. Below is my Dockerfile.
FROM node:22-slim AS build

WORKDIR /app
RUN rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm cache clean --force && npm cache verify
RUN npm install -g npm@latest && npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/
RUN ng build --configuration=production


FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=build /app/dist/test/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/dist/test/server /usr/share/nginx/server

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx-found.conf /etc/nginx/extra-conf.d/backend-found.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

I am facing issue like
=> ERROR [build 6/8] RUN npm install                                                                                                                               19.6s
------                                                                                                                                                                    
 > [build 6/8] RUN npm install:                                                                                                                                           
4.133 npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported                                                                               
5.478 npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
5.501 npm warn tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
5.643 npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
5.851 npm warn tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
6.746 npm warn deprecated critters@0.0.24: Ownership of Critters has moved to the Nuxt team, who will be maintaining the project going forward. If you'd like to keep using Critters, please switch to the actively-maintained fork at https://github.com/danielroe/beasties
**19.46 npm error code TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE
19.46 npm error TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format**
19.46 npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-12-17T12_38_08_326Z-debug-0.log
------
Dockerfile:7
--------------------
   5 |     RUN npm install -g npm@latest && npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
   6 |     COPY package*.json /app/
   7 | >>> RUN npm install
   8 |     COPY ./ /app/
   9 |     RUN ng build --configuration=production
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I am using ubuntu linux system. I have tried windows wsl and ec2 linux. Sometime it works and docker build done. but major cases it stop here.
Any suggestion please guide.
Thanks

Does this system work with plain npm, without involving Docker at all?  If the NPM packages are corrupt and the packages aren't being maintained, this won't be something you can fix and it won't be specific to a Docker setup.

Expected Behavior
The packages should be installed
The reason might be The NPM registry is down in APAC
I had the same issue on step npm install
I have added RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com/ --global before npm install
Solution
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com/ --global
add this before installing npm in your case
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com/ --global
RUN npm install -g npm@latest && npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install 

it worked for me :)
